# How to find lowest elevation change using raster data and w.r.t muliple polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, dem, elevation, slope

I am trying to complete a spatial analysis which yields areas (parcels of land) which are comprised of polygons (in an attribute table) that correspond to the lowest land slope regions or smallest elevation change.

I've got the DEM, and I attempted using **Spatial Join Tool** to merge the attribute data together to the pink polygons, but I'm not sure how to spatially analyse it in order to yield the results I need.

[image: Picture of my ArcMap model]

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Zonal Statistics or Zonal Statistics as Table. If you would like the result to be smallest elevation change then use DEM and pick RANGE as Statistics Type. If you would like the result to be minimum slope then use the result of Slope Tool instead of DEM and MINIMUM or the one thar suits you best as Statistics Type

Comment: This has definitely worked out quite well. I've used Zonal Statistics and selected the DEM value as 'Input value raster' and the polygon (parcels of land) as 'Input raster or feature zone data', the statistics type output was set to MEAN which yields the average elevation change for each region of that shapefile. I also found it's a little bit easier to interpret SLOPE attribute value rather than using height, so I decided to create a SLOPE raster file and use that in place of the DEM for the Zonal Statistics tool, excellent results in the end.